# How to show recent topics from my phpBB forum in my drupal website?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, phpbb

I have setup a phpBB forum and people are using it. It has a decent level of activity.

I have setup a Drupal 6.15 website and I want to show the recent topics from that phpBB forum on this website.

Both are separate domain names, if it matters.

I've been searching since morning in Google for a module to do that but the results beat around the bush and so far I haven't found one.

**I don't want any merging or porting of data from phpBB to drupal database. People will still use the phpBB thing for forums and visit my website for other things. I just want to showcase the recent posts in my phpBB forum, on my Drupal website.**

Can someone help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install phpbbforum module, setup it and turn off user synchronisation and just use recent posts block.

Answer (score -1):

No module exists. You have to provide yourself ( I did successfully ) but if databases are from different providers I find it quite difficult